# __setattr__ not detecting .append() changes

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making an inheritable class which can lock values (making them un-editable), in the classes it is used in, it works fine except once an attribute is locked and you append to it. For some reason **setattr** isn't picking up .append() and I'm honestly not sure how to detect/stop it, can anyone help me?

My code is below:

```
class valuelocker:

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):

        # Prevents manual changes to the __locked__ attribute
        if name == "__locked__":
            for attr in self.__locked__:
                if attr not in value:
                    raise Exception("locked attribute cannot be removed")
                elif self.__locked__[attr] != value[attr]:
                    raise Exception("locked attribute cannot be changed")
        # Prevents locked attributes from being changed
        elif name in self.__locked__:
            raise Exception("locked attribute cannot be changed")

        # Changes the value of an attribute 
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
        if name != "__dict__":
            self.__dict__[name] = value

    # Adds an attribute to the __locked__ attibute
    def lock(self, name):
        self.__locked__[name] = eval(f"self.{name}")

    __locked__ = {}

class test(valuelocker):
    List = []

t = test()
t.lock("List")

# Works for some reason (it's not doing what it's supposed to)
t.List.append(None)

# Doesn't work (it's doing what it's supposed to)
t.List = [None]
```

Comment: The `setattr` is not called, because `append` keeps the object (same list), but mutates it (different data), i.e. it changes it "in-place".  There are tons of tutorials about this topic.

Comment: Is there a way to moderate the mutation like setattr does?

Comment: No, there is no such mutable on/off switch. Also, please note that you could play with `__setattr__` and similar in classes you have defined. But you wanted to lock existing objects, i.e. instances of classes that are not under your control.